# Zapier Webhooks add data to default payload

Tags: shopify, webhooks, zapier

I am setting up a Zap on Zapier and i have been trying to send a payload from Shopify(create order) to a Webhook which is sending data to an API. The problem i am having is adding data to the default payload(all data). I want to send all the data from the payload plus some additional attributes which i am configuring on the Data section, but this replaces the default-all data.

Is there a way to add a value to all the payload? I know i have the option to add the value by header or query string but i would like to add to the body instead. I am currently viewing the **custom request** but it seems complicated to configure the whole request to just add one value.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team. This is a great question!

The short answer is that it's not possible to do quite what you want. You'll need to map each property into that data box like you're doing and add the custom properties you want.

That said, we track all feature requests that come in through tickets, so if you'd like to voice your support and get notified if/when this does get implemented, I'd suggest emailing in to `contact@zapier.com`.